# Colon used in timestamp gives for variable an syntax error

Tags: bash

The array in the fields seperator gives these style of timecodes (hours:minutes:seconds).

```
01:00:00
```

As I put this in the following code:

```
maximum=25
count=0
countrow=1

 while [ $count -lt $maximum ]; do
    let start$countrow="${fields[$count]}"
        count=$(($count+1))
    let end$countrow="${fields[$count]}"
        count=$(($count+1))
        countrow=$(($countrow+1))
 done
```

Should give the output as:

```
start1="01:00:00"
start2="02:00:00"
```

But gives me this error:

```
start1=01:00:00: syntax error in expression (error token is ":00:00")
```

I tried many ways, I guess the colon is the problem but don't know how to "bypass" that in the code?

Comment: Math contexts works on integers. A value with colons in it isn't an integer.

Comment: ...btw, `start$countrow=...` isn't exactly best practice for indirect assignment. See [the relevant section of BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables)

Comment: Also, your code isn't currently a MCVE -- I can't copy and paste it and get the exact same output. Please assign your `fields` array in a manner identical to what you're doing in practice.

Comment: (Also, if you're using bash rather than /bin/sh -- and please tag for only one of these very distinct languages -- `start` should probably be a single array, rather than having a single variable name per entry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish (an English-language description of the problem you're trying to solve would help), but assuming that you have something like the following:

```
fields=( 01:00:00 02:30:00 03:15:45 )
```

...you can iterate through them as follows:

```
for field_idx in "${!fields[@]}"; do

  # read field into hour/minute/second variables
  IFS=: read -r h m s <<<"${fields[$field_idx]}"

  # put time into start$idx one hour after the field entry
  printf -v "start$(( field_idx + 1 ))" '%02d:%02d:%02d' \
    "$(( ${h#0} + 1 ))" "$m" "$s"

done
```

...thus creating variables "start1", "start2" and "start3", each with a time one hour later than that given in the associated `fields` entry.

The `${h#0}` syntax strips any leading 0, to prevent the numbers from being parsed as octal (which would make `08` and `09` invalid).